# Get configuration or global variables into modules definition in NestJS

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, global-variables

In NestJS, I have something like this:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        AnotherModule.register({
            callBackUrl: 'http://localhost:3333/callback',
            merchantId: '124312352134123',
            currency: 'CAD',
        }),
    ],
    providers: [PaymentsService, ...PaymentsProviders],
    exports: [PaymentsService],
})
export class PaymentsModule {}
```

Whenever I need to get `merchantId` from global variables or configuration module, NestJS has something called `useFactory`. but it works with `registerAsync` method, instead of `register`.
In this case, AnotherModule doesn't have `registerAsync` method. What can I do?

Question: why I can't use `process.env` here? (I know when I have configuration module, it's not the best solution but I want to know it's reason)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you *have the access* to the `process.env`, but only to those variables that are already present in the environment, eg `NODE_PATH`. If you're asking about variables from `*.env` files, and why they aren't accessible at this point, the answer is: because they haven't been loaded into `process.env` by anything. When you use the NestJS `ConfigModule`, it parses `.env` files, and loads their contents into environment, thus `process.env`.

If you have a look at, say, `dotenv` package (or `python-dotenv`, in Python it works exactly alike), you need to *load configuration* from the files first, and only then, they become accessible to the application's environment.